# Vue js how to call method wen prop change

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, popup

I am calling a component into a model popup
i want to load dynamic data in popup when each different click event

this is my code in html of parent component

```
<a v-if="days.label == 1" href="#" @click="viewTimeLog(employee.id, days.date)">
                                        <span class="badge badge-success">
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="view-emp-time-log" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div v-if="employee_id_number" class="modal-content">
            <employeeattentancelog :employeeIdNumber="employee_id_number" :attentanceDate="attentance_date"></employeeattentancelog>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <!-- / Modal -->
```

this is the script in parent component

```
<script>
import EmployeeAttentanceLog from "./EmployeeAttentanceLog.vue";
export default {
   components : {employeeattentancelog: EmployeeAttentanceLog},
   data() {
      employee_id_number : 0,
      attentance_date : '',
   },
methods : {
        viewTimeLog(empId, date) {
            this.employee_id_number = empId;
            this.attentance_date = date;
            $("#view-emp-time-log").modal("show");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

this is my script in EmployeeAttendanceLog.Vue

```
<script>
export default {
    props : ['employeeIdNumber','attentanceDate'],
    data() {
        return {
            employee_id : this.employeeIdNumber,
            date : this.attentanceDate
        }
    }
</script>
```

i need to call a method in EmployeeAttentanceLog.vue for load dinamic data inside popup when the employee_id and date change
How can i do this. I am totaly stucked anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't watch both props on one function, you'll have to add one watcher for every variable you want to trigger an action on change. You can create one handler (One single function) to be performed inside each watcher, like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  props : ['employeeIdNumber','attentanceDate'],
  data() {
    return {
      employee_id : this.employeeIdNumber,
      date : this.attentanceDate
    }
  }
  methods: {}
  watch: {
    employeeIdNumber(newVal, oldVal){
      this.handler('param')
    },
    attenanceDate(newVal, oldVal){
      this.handler('param')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handler(params) {
      // do something here
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
export default {
    props : ['employeeIdNumber','attentanceDate'],
    data() {
        return {
            employee_id : this.employeeIdNumber,
            date : this.attentanceDate
        }
    }
   watch: {
    employeeIdNumber(newVal, oldVal){
     this.employee_id = newVal
    }
  }
</script>

You can you vue JS's watch property to observe the change in any property or data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
can you please show me how can i watch both employeeIdNumber and attendanceDate  is changed in one function ?